What are Excel labels called and how are they stored?
My company recently implemented this as a requirement before saving a document:

In this case, the options are:

But I'm guessing that's specific to my company, not an Excel thing.  I could be wrong.
I want to be able to access this via all of the usual suspects (VBA, Interop, EPPlus, ClosedXML) and some unusual suspects (Dev Express) but don't really know what it's called.  When I search for Excel Label, I get lots of stuff thats...  not this.
What is this object/property called?  Bonus:  Snippet of how to access via VBA?

Alt + F11 (or FN + ALT + F11)is the fast way to open VBA, but a lot of times add-ins like that are locked behind a password by the vendor or developer. I think it's likely linked to security stuff based on your picture, and would speak with IT if it changes permissions on how you share or how others access the document. I would choose somewhere on the tighter security selections if it's sensitive and you don't plan on sharing it.

Check SensitivityLabel object (Office) at least for VBA. There you can check methods, events and properties.

That looks like a "Sensitivity Label" - mandatory by IT policy. See Microsoft Learn: Sensitivity Labels
I found some useful VBA at MrExcel

Would not have found this on my own...  THANK YOU
